# Azure VPN clients unable to communicate with devices on another local network which has site-to-site VPN to Azure

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have a virtual gateway to a virtual network which has a site-to-site VPN with my on-prem network.

Within the same virtual network gateway, I have a point-to-site VPN configuration to enable devices from other remote locations outside of Azure.

The point-to-site clients are able to communicate to Azure, and my devices on my on-prem network can communicate to Azure.

I can communicate from a virtual machine in my virtual network in Azure to both my On-Prem network connect through the site-to-site VPN, and my clients connected to the point-to-site VPN.

However my issue is devices connecting to Azure with the point-to-site VPN are unable to communicate with my on-prem network which has the site-to-site VPN into Azure, I need communication between my point-to-site clients, and my on-prem network. I assume there is a configuration somewhere in Azure that i'm missing to enable this?

See above, i'm unable to get my point-to-site clients to communicate with my on-prem network

Answer (score 0):

To communicate vpn with on-prem network which has the site-to-site VPN into Azure you can mak use of BGP

BGP enables the Azure VPN gateways and your on-premises VPN devices, called BGP peers to exchange "routes" that will communicate with both gateways on the availability and reachability for those prefixes to go through the gateways or routers involved By propagating the routes that a BGP gateway acquires from one BGP peer to all other BGP peers, and also transit routing among other networks.

In you virtual network gateway under configuration enabled configure BGP like below:

[image]

Add virtual network like below:

[image]

In local network gateway in BGP setting add ip address to communicate like below :

[image]

Then, In connection -> configuration try to enable BGP like below:

[image]

In virtual network gateway under montioring -> BGP peer now you can able to coonect with you oon permise successfully like below:

[image]

To more in detail please refer this link:

[Azure VPN Gateway: About P2S routing - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-point-to-site-routing#multivnets2sbranchbgp)

[Configure BGP for VPN Gateway: Portal - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/bgp-howto)